# Add standard content type “document” to existing document libary

Tags: sharepoint-2013, contenttype

I want to add the standard content type "document" to existing document library and get following error message.

---

Conflict while saving

The changes you make are in conflict with the same time by another user changes made. In order for your changes to take effect, click your web browser's " Back " button to update that page and submit your changes again.

---

Hope anybody can help me.

Comment: How are you adding the Content Type? SharePoint Web interface or by code?

Comment: I´m adding the Content Type via SharePoint Web interface. I tried it with IE and SharePoint Designer. Any ideas?

Comment: This usually happens if there is an event receiver on the list, performing some activity as a different user. Is there any customization on the farm? In particular any event receivers. 
You can check it using SharePoint Manager.

Comment: No, there is no customization on the farm whether an list receiver, workflow, etc. This was also my first idea to check. Can it be that there are anyway customization which I cannot see?

Comment: You will be able to see the event receivers attached to a list / content type using SharePoint Manager.
This will also include any sort of customization... But I am getting a feeling that you have already checked it.

Comment: Yes, I have already checked it and there is no event receiver or sort of customization. Any other ideas?